# Dymo Label QR automatically formats linked data as website

Tags: label, qr-code, dymo

I am working to create Dymo labels using Dymo Connect templates. I wish to add QR codes containing linked data text. Whenever I link the data to the QR code it automatically formats the QR code as a website and adds "url:" at the beginning of the text. Is there a way to prevent dymo from formatting my data as a website when I add the linked data? I would prefer it to format as text.

Answer (score 0):

Create your template as normal, but instead of a QR code, use a normal barcode. Open the template file with a text editor, then change the `BarcodeFormat` tag to contain `QRCOde`. You can also change the size to Large if needed.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DesktopLabel Version="1">
  <DYMOLabel Version="3">
    ...
    <DynamicLayoutManager>
      ...
      <LabelObjects>
        ...
        <BarcodeObject>
          ...
          <BarcodeFormat>QRCode</BarcodeFormat>
          ...
          <Size>Large</Size>
          ...
        </BarcodeObject>
      </LabelObjects>
    </DynamicLayoutManager>
  </DYMOLabel>
  ...
</DesktopLabel>
```

https://developers.dymo.com/2011/11/29/printing-qr-code-part-1/